# Writing an explicit function (hard)

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I need to explicitly write a function as follows:

For any set C with at least 2 (different) objects, find a function $F ∈ (C → (C → C)) → (C → C)$ such that $∀ f ∈ C → (C → C).F (f) \notin Imf$  .

Any ideas how to approach this? Thanks!

Comment: [Cantor's diagonal argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor's_diagonal_argument).

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? I know this proof and still have trouble solving

Comment: Any $f : C \to ( C \to C)$ is essentially a family of functions $\phi_x : C \to C$, 
indexed by $x \in C$. What you are asking to do is find a systematic way to construct a new function $F(f) : C \to C$ which is different from  all these $\phi_x$.